# Wondering how to execute html in if else statement using php

Tags: php, html

I am very new at PHP and I don't even know if this is possible but I was wondering if it was possible to only show the comment section only if the user is logged in. I use the following the check if the user if logged in or not.

```
<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['name'])){
/* this displays the comment section */
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://mywebsite.com" data-width="650" data-numposts="10"></div>
        } else {
                echo "Please login";
                }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

do it like this and let me know.

```
<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['name'])){ ?>
  <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://mywebsite.com" data-width="650" data-numposts="10"></div>
  <?php  } else {
            echo "Please login";
            }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

enclose the div to echo. Everytime you want to print HTML code inside of a PHP code just print it using `echo "html code here";`

```
echo '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://mywebsite.com" data-width="650" data-numposts="10"></div>';
```